# Why is state.filter in Redux Toolkit not filtering the array?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, filter, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm creating a goal tracker with Redux Toolkit for learning purposes. The goals are held in an array which I push new values to with no issues, but when I try to state.filter the same array, the value isn't removed. Redux devtools shows deleteGoal running, but it's not deleting anything.

I tried using splice, filtering current(state), logging state, and placing debuggers throughout the various files.
I noticed that state logs as a proxy, but if that were the problem, why does state.push() work and state.filter() doesn't?

The array (in the slice):

```
const initialState = [
    {
        id: 1,
        input: 'drink water',
        achieved: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        input: 'in bed by 11:15',
        achieved: true
        },
    {
        id: 3,
        input: 'study 2hrs',
        achieved: true
    },
]
```

The actions:

```
export const goalsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'goals',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addGoal: (state, action) => {
        state.push(action.payload)
      },
    deleteGoal: (state, action) => {
      const goalId = action.payload
      state.filter((goal) => goal.id !== goalId)
      console.log(current(state))
    },
  },
})
```

The component where it's rendered:

```
<Text
        fontSize="3xl"
        fontWeight={600}
        >your goals:</Text>
            {goals.map((goal, index) => (
                    <li 
                    key={index}
                    onDoubleClick = {goal => {
                        dispatch(deleteGoal(goal.target.textContent))
                        // console.log(goal)
                        // console.log(goal.target.textContent)
                    }}
                    className='goal-text'
                    >
                        
                        {goal.input}
                    </li> 
            
        ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `filter()` does not modify the array, rather it creates a shadow copy of it, perhaps the intended action in `deleteGoal` should be:

```
// Only for redux-toolkit

state = state.filter((goal) => goal.id !== goalId)
```

According to `redux-toolkit` [document](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation) (as opposed to `Redux`):

> To make things easier, createReducer uses immer to let you write reducers as if they were mutating the state directly. In reality, the reducer receives a proxy state that translates all mutations into equivalent copy operations.

More examples about how `redux-toolkit` allows "mutating" update of immutable state in reducers for: [`createSlice`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice).

Comment: While this works it suffers from the same issue as OP - you're changing state in-place which goes against Redux usage advice. Changing state this way (via side-effects) is unpredictable and could introduce rendering inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

`state.filter()` is not working as you expect because you need to return the result in order to update the state; not change it in place. e.g.

```
return state.filter((goal) => goal.id !== goalId)
```

`state.push()` *does* work as you expect because it's changing the state in-place as opposed to returning a value. This is arguably against the best practice of Redux - your `addGoal` function could be changed to something like

```
addGoal: (state, action) => {
  // return a new array, don't modify the existing state in place
  return [
    ...state, // copy the current array of goals
    (action.payload) // add the new goal
  ]
},
```

See https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-mutate-state for more details

Answer (score 0):

Redux tookit use immer under the hood that allow you to write mutable syntax. I guess its the must thing to not write it immutable code else there is no use of immer. I face same problem and simple return the new array from filter.`

```
erase: (state, action) => {
      return state.filter(
        (element) => JSON.stringify(element) !== JSON.stringify(action.payload)
      );
```

`
it removed the object that didnt match. and it worked.